# Ler e manipular dados de json usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dizem que Json é simples. Mas estou penando e muito.

Seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "http://meusite.com/", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

o resultado o console.log é

```
[
    {"id":"769","cidade":"minhacidade","estado":"PR"},
    {"id":"855","cidade":"Caram","estado":"PR"}
]
```

Exatamente o que preciso. (até aqui consegui)
Mas a partir desse ponto não consigo sair. 
Preciso manipular esses resultado.Quebrar em pedaços.

Por em DIVs.

Mas não consigo (pesquisei o google todo) nada da certo.

O que eu tenho que fazer para que eu posso por ex:

- Printar na tela o ID da segunda cidade.
- O segundo estado

E assim por diante pq esse Json vai crescer e muito.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como o HTML deve ser?

Comment: Olha, só me ensinando como por um dado desse Json em uma DIV simples. O resto eu faço. 

Por exemplo o (Id 2) em um DIV.

Não preciso de mais nada

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cara, já sei o que deve estar rolando.
O seu retorno de estar vindo em string,
você tem que converter em objeto para poder manipula-lo.

Observe:

```
var valorRetornado = '[{"id":"769","cidade":"minhacidade","estado":"PR"},{"id":"855","cidade":"Caram","estado":"PR"}]'
        // convertendo a string em objeto
        var obj = JSON.parse(valorRetornado);

        obj.forEach(function(o, index){
            console.log(o.cidade);
        });
```

Os colaboradores deram vários exemplos,
mas em todos eles convertem objeto em string, 
quando na verdade vc deve fazer o contrário.

Comment: Verdade, observando mais e aprendendo percebi isso. 
Por isso mudei a forma de receber. 

Você esta certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Amigo você tem um objeto em mãos.
Para manipular o objeto você usa a sintaxe:

```
*object[key] ou object.key*
```

Em seu caso vai ficar:

```
console.log( data[0]['id'] );
```

Para inserir esses dados numa DIV ou qualquer elemento, você pode fazer isso de N maneiras.
Pode ser pelo seletor CLASS ou pelo seletor ID, tem outras formas formas de fazer, mas a principio são essas.
Voce pode ler a documentação do Jquery para maiores detalhes.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Bons estudos amigos.

Comment: Já fiz assim tbm o resultado é undefined

Comment: A ok amigo, coloca um indice antes da chave, exemplo: data[0]['id'], veja o que acontece.

Comment: Você esta certo. 

Mas mudei o método no lugar de $get usei $getJSON

Ai deu certo 

console.log(data[1]['cidade']);

Comment: Beleza, agora retire o -1 e marque como a melhor resposta hehe

Answer (score 2):

Nesse `data` estás a receber um JSON. No caso de ele ainda estar em *String*  podes converter em Array. A partir daí é simples. Um exemplo podia ser assim:

```
data = typeof data == 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data; // para garantir que o formato é correto
// e depois:
data.forEach(... etc
```

Exemplo:

```
[{
    "id": "769",
    "cidade": "minhacidade",
    "estado": "PR"
}, {
    "id": "855",
    "cidade": "Caram",
    "estado": "PR"
}].forEach(function(elementoDaArray) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'); // criar o elemento
    div.id = elementoDaArray.id; // dar-lhe o ID do objeto
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(elementoDaArray); // dar-lhe conteúdo
    document.body.appendChild(div); // inserir no DOM
});
```

**Exemplo:** https://jsfiddle.net/g3gmzk2p/

Se quiseres usar jQuery para fazer o mesmo [pode ser assim](https://jsfiddle.net/g3gmzk2p/1/):

```
$('<div/>', {
    id: elementoDaArray.id,
    html: JSON.stringify(elementoDaArray)
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

---

Em vez do `$.get` podias usar o `$.getJSON` que já te dá um JSON. Para iterar o objeto que recebes podes usar o `data.forEach(function(...` como fiz em cima, ou um ciclo `for`.

Comment: Fiz da sua forma e funcionou também. 
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido mudei a forma de chamar, para  $.getJSON .

```js
$.getJSON( "http://meusite.com/", function( data ) {
//console.log(data);

console.log(data[0]['cidade']);
console.log(data[1]['cidade']);

});
```

Esse método me volta um obejto (o outro um texto).

Com isso consegui acessar cada índice. 
Com console.log(data[1]['cidade']);

Deu certo.

Também com $get deu certo. 
**Então vou deixar as duas maneiras para quem precisar.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "http://meusite.com/", function( data ) {


data = typeof data == 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
data.forEach(function(elementoDaArray) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    id = elementoDaArray.id;
    cidade = elementoDaArray.cidade;
  
    console.log(cidade);
    console.log(id);


    //div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(elementoDaArray);
    //document.body.appendChild(div);


});
```

Comment: So uma dica, seria muito bom você usar success e error, pois se houver um erro nessa chamada, você pode tratar o erro e imprimir algo amigável ao usuário.
É só uma dica.

Comment: Sim irei usar. 

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

$.get é uma versão simplificada do $.ajax, possui menos parâmetros. Para usar o json deve-se usar ajax, já que o mesmo tem o parâmetro datatype, que deve ser definido para json.

neste caso:

```
$.ajax({
method:"get",
dataType:"json",
url:"seusite",
success: function(data){
console.log(data["id"]);
}

N
```

este exemplo eu pego o id, para os outros é só usar data[nome].

Abraço

Comment: Tentei assim tbm Mas recebo isso 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input